# objective c iphone musicplayer crashing

Tags: objective-c, ios, jailbreak, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am creating a non appstore jailbreak tweak and I came across a problem that causes my app to crash.

I am using `musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];`

the music player has complete functionality, play/pause, next, previous. it displays the title of the song, the artist, the artwork and everything.

the problem seems to be the loading and unloading of the musicplayer.

for example, if i am running the app, and i close the iphone's Music app, it will cause my app to crash. also if i load the app without the Music app running in the background it will crash.

as long as the music app is running in the background my app will not crash.
can anyone help me with this?

is something to be set to nil? or how do i go about releasing them?
should they be synthesize/property?

Comment: What exactly do you want your tweak to do?  Do you just want to gracefully handle the iPod app shutdown, so you don't crash?  Or do you still want to keep playing music after the user has shutdown the iPod manually (which seems strange to me)?

Comment: The first one. I just want to be able to handle the shutdown without crashing.

Comment: Can you give us information about **how** it's crashing?  Which line of code?  Does `iPodMusicPlayer` return `nil` after the music player app shuts down?

Comment: Check out Apple's AddMusic sample app, it might help. Alternatively you might need to post a stripped down version of your code so we can see what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem also for my tweak, and I couldn't figure out a way to fix it. I ended up using the AVPlayer Method, It seems to work well for me. Granted I only need to play one song, so if you need to play a playlist of some sorts you are out of luck.

I used it like the following in the mediapickerclass:

```
NSURL *url = [[mediaItemCollection.items objectAtIndex: 0] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url];
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[player play];
```

If you need you need to reference it from somewhere else you can just write the url to a .plist

Comment: unfortunately, I am looking to play music from the actual Music library and not just one song.